# nested data from XML as tibble or Dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, tidyverse, tibble

I'm stuck at work with a code problem in R that I can't solve. I have the following XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Votacion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/v1">
  <Id>15446</Id>
  <Descripcion>Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574</Descripcion>
  <Fecha>2012-06-13T14:47:29</Fecha>
  <TotalSi>12</TotalSi>
  <TotalNo>2</TotalNo>
  <TotalAbstencion>2</TotalAbstencion>
  <TotalDispensado>0</TotalDispensado>
  <Quorum Valor="1">Quórum Simple</Quorum>
  <Resultado Valor="2">Unánime</Resultado>
  <Tipo Valor="3">Proyecto de Acuerdo</Tipo>
  <Votos>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>810</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Ascencio</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Mansilla</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>855</Id>
        <Nombre>Carlos Abel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Jarpa</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Wevar</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>862</Id>
        <Nombre>Pablo</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Lorenzini</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Basso</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="0">En Contra</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>898</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Silber</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Romo</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
  </Votos>
</Votacion>
```

I got the data from this api
https://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/WServices/WSLegislativo.asmx/retornarVotacionDetalle?prmVotacionId=15446

I want to process the data to obtain a  tibble like this

| Id | Nombre | ApellidoPaterno | ApellidoMaterno | OpcionVoto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 810 | Gabriel | Acencio | Mansilla | Afirmativo |
| 855 | Abel | Jarpa | Webar | Afirmativo |
| 862 | Pablo | Lorenzini | Basso | En Contra |

Any kind of help will be amazing, please !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something inspired by https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html :

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

read_xml(xml_str) %>% 
  xml_ns_strip() %>% 
  xml_find_all("//Voto") %>% 
  as_list() %>% 
  tibble(lst = .) %>% 

  # A tibble: 4 × 1

  unnest_wider(lst) %>% 

  # A tibble: 4 × 2
  # Diputado           OpcionVoto
  # 1 <named list [4]> <list [1]>

  unnest_wider("Diputado") %>% 

  # A tibble: 4 × 5
  #   Id         Nombre     ApellidoPaterno ApellidoMaterno OpcionVoto
  #   <list>     <list>     <list>          <list>          <list>    
  # 1 <list [1]> <list [1]> <list [1]>      <list [1]>      <list [1]>  

  unnest_longer(everything())
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Id    Nombre      ApellidoPaterno ApellidoMaterno OpcionVoto
#>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>           <chr>           <chr>     
#> 1 810   Gabriel     Ascencio        Mansilla        Afirmativo
#> 2 855   Carlos Abel Jarpa           Wevar           Afirmativo
#> 3 862   Pablo       Lorenzini       Basso           En Contra 
#> 4 898   Gabriel     Silber          Romo            Afirmativo
```

Input:

```r
xml_str <- 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Votacion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/v1">
  <Id>15446</Id>
  <Descripcion>Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574</Descripcion>
  <Fecha>2012-06-13T14:47:29</Fecha>
  <TotalSi>12</TotalSi>
  <TotalNo>2</TotalNo>
  <TotalAbstencion>2</TotalAbstencion>
  <TotalDispensado>0</TotalDispensado>
  <Quorum Valor="1">Quórum Simple</Quorum>
  <Resultado Valor="2">Unánime</Resultado>
  <Tipo Valor="3">Proyecto de Acuerdo</Tipo>
  <Votos>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>810</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Ascencio</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Mansilla</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>855</Id>
        <Nombre>Carlos Abel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Jarpa</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Wevar</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>862</Id>
        <Nombre>Pablo</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Lorenzini</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Basso</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="0">En Contra</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>898</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Silber</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Romo</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
  </Votos>
</Votacion>'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

xml <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Votacion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/v1">
  <Id>15446</Id>
  <Descripcion>Proyecto de Acuerdo N° 574</Descripcion>
  <Fecha>2012-06-13T14:47:29</Fecha>
  <TotalSi>12</TotalSi>
  <TotalNo>2</TotalNo>
  <TotalAbstencion>2</TotalAbstencion>
  <TotalDispensado>0</TotalDispensado>
  <Quorum Valor="1">Quórum Simple</Quorum>
  <Resultado Valor="2">Unánime</Resultado>
  <Tipo Valor="3">Proyecto de Acuerdo</Tipo>
  <Votos>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>810</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Ascencio</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Mansilla</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>855</Id>
        <Nombre>Carlos Abel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Jarpa</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Wevar</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>862</Id>
        <Nombre>Pablo</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Lorenzini</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Basso</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="0">En Contra</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
    <Voto>
      <Diputado>
        <Id>898</Id>
        <Nombre>Gabriel</Nombre>
        <ApellidoPaterno>Silber</ApellidoPaterno>
        <ApellidoMaterno>Romo</ApellidoMaterno>
      </Diputado>
      <OpcionVoto Valor="1">Afirmativo</OpcionVoto>
    </Voto>
  </Votos>
</Votacion>')

xml_ns(xml)
# d1  <-> http://opendata.camara.cl/camaradiputados/v1
# xsd <-> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
# xsi <-> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance


xml %>% xml_find_all(".//d1:Voto") %>% 
  map_dfr(~ set_names(
    c(.x %>% xml_child("d1:Diputado") %>% xml_children() %>% map(xml_text),
      .x %>% xml_child("d1:OpcionVoto") %>% xml_text()),
    c(.x %>% xml_child("d1:Diputado") %>% xml_children() %>% map(xml_name), "OpcionVoto")))

# A tibble: 4 × 5
#  Id    Nombre      ApellidoPaterno ApellidoMaterno OpcionVoto
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>           <chr>           <chr>     
#1 810   Gabriel     Ascencio        Mansilla        Afirmativo
#2 855   Carlos Abel Jarpa           Wevar           Afirmativo
#3 862   Pablo       Lorenzini       Basso           En Contra 
#4 898   Gabriel     Silber          Romo            Afirmativo
```